# excel - how to segment a table?

Tags: excel

I have a table with 12 months of sales data that looks like this

```
dec-19 jan-20 feb-20 ... nov-20
999    999    999        999
999    999    999        999
999    999    999        999
```

is there any way I can group this into 4 columns of three months each? the output should look like this

```
2019-2020| 2020    ...
dec-feb  | mar-may |
8991     | 8991    |
```

Comment: You may solve it with "pivot" tables. There are sevaral tutorials like this: https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-create-pivot-table-tutorial-ht

Comment: @marsh-wiggle pivot tables can only group by quarter so in this case it would split december into a different column. I want a rolling 3 month sum.